# A set in Hilbert space where all triangles are isosceles

Tags: set-theory, hilbert-spaces, triangles

In one of P. Erdős papers ("My Scottish Book Problems") he mentioned a set of power $\mathfrak c$ in Hilbert space where all triangles are isosceles. What is the definition of this set?

Comment: Reference of _My Scottish Book Problems_ for instance [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=itYLCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Watson I can't consult this site. However, there is a whole website on this in Poland, together with an english PDF of the Scottish Book, see the links on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Book). Not sure exactly how it relates to Erdős' *"My Scottish Book Problems"*.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I quote from Erdős' _My Scottish Book Problems_ : "Hajnal and I have an easy example in Hilbert space of a set of power $\mathfrak c$ where all triangles are isoceles […]"

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in P. Komjath "Set Theory:Geometric and Real":

The situation changes radically if we replace $R^n$ with the Hilbert space $l^\infty$ of infinite real vectors $(x_0, x_l,...)$ with $\Sigma x^2_i$; finite. An observation due to Erdos, Kakutani, Oxtoby, L.M.Kelly, Nordhaus, and possibly many others is that in this case there are continuum many points with pairwise rational distance.

As it is easy not to find a proof I sketch one. Work in the Hilbert space
where an orthonormal basis is $\{b_s\}$ where s can be any finite 0-1 sequence.
To every infinite 0-1 sequence z associate $a(z) = \Sigma \lambda_n b_{z|n}$ where z|n denotes the string of the first n terms of z and $\lambda_n = \sqrt{3}  \times 2^{-(n+l)}$. If $z \neq z'$ first differ
at the (n + 1)-st position then $(a(z) - a(z'))^2 = \Sigma\{\lambda_i^2: i > n\} = 4^{-n}$ so the
distance between a(z) and a(z') is $2^{-n}$ . It is easy to see that every triangle
in this construction is isosceles. I don't know if there is a similar (or any)
construction of continuum many points such that all three-element subsets
form a triangle with nonzero rational area.

Comment: Interesting construction. Where does the $\sqrt{3}$ go? And what is $l$ in the definition on $\lambda_n$?